# How to set animation speed in libgdx 2d particle editor for sprite mode animated?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am using the animated sprite mode for particles images. The number of image is 10. But what I noticed that the animation speed or frame rate is controlled by the life property of the editor. I need to speed up the animation, but can't find any option for it. I noticed that for animated sprite there is option for animation speed in Godot game engine.

Answer (score 0):

I have found out a way. Need to change the frame generation technique in ParticleEmitter class.